# Can I apply Google's "Scan and Match" feature to music I have already uploaded?

Tags: google, google-play-music

With Google's "Scan and Match" feature, I understand that when I go to upload new music, Google will scan the music prior to uploading, and if Google has a copy already, it just adds their copy to my music collection online (instead of uploading it again).  Sometimes Google's copy is higher quality than mine, so I would like to apply this to ALL of my music (including already-uploaded music).  Is there any way to do this?

The alternative I see is to just delete everything and start over, but that sucks.  :-(

Comment: AFAIK this will be coming but for now no, it doesn't retro-actively  match your existing library.

Comment: Does Google really not match your existing library? Do they state that explicitly? Has anyone experienced something that proves they are not? I'm really interested, it can't be hard for Google to match all existing music...

Comment: I'm trying to understand something similar. In my case "Scan and Match" could only recognize 70% of songs and the remaining 30% were uploaded to Google Play Music servers, as expected. Now, is there a chance that at some point in time those tracks will be finally matched by "scan and match" and replaced by Google's high-quality version? (I'm only concerned with the streaming quality, not the quality of downloaded files). I just started using Google Play Music, but you guys have been dealing with it since 2012, so has something like this ever happened to files in your library, so far?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this will be happening automatically over time. Here's the relevant portion of the [Google Help page on the feature](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2920799).

> If you’re a longtime Google Play Music user, you don’t need to re-upload your files to have them matched. In the next few months, we'll automatically match what we can of your existing library.

Comment: As of 2017, what if a track isn't immediately recognized? Is there a chance that it will be recognized at some point in time in the future? Has it ever happened to you?